# Distributing Apps Outside the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a small app that I want to distribute to a small group of people and was following the Distributing Apps Outside the App Store instructions.  I have Archived the app with my developer ID and IOS Distribution Cert, created the Manifest.plist file. uploaded them to the website which is HTTPS with a root cert that is on the IOS9 trusted list and used the sample html link provided in the instructions.

clicking the link with Safari from an iPhone 9.2 I get an alert that say:
""Cannot install applications because the certificate for the "website" is not valid""

Any help on why this error(Alert) is happening and how to get the app to install would be appreciated.

Comment: Which instructions are you following, exactly? You can't distribute iOS applications to arbitrary users outside the App Store environment. There are different instructions for using Enterprise distribution or ad-hoc / TestFlight distribution.

Comment: I was using the Distributing Apps Outside the Mac App Store document for the archiving and the Install in-house apps wireless document.  In the latter document it describes how to setup a HTTPS one page website with the link example for users to access and download the app.

Comment: with Ad-hoc provisioning.  It is just a app for family members and they are are well disbursed so I can't just plug their phones into xCode or techie enough to give me their phones ID.  Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: "Distributing Apps Outside the Mac App Store" is a document about Mac applications. It's unlikely to be particularly-useful in distributing iOS apps. The Enterprise Developer program is probably more-trouble (and cost) than it's worth, unless you already have a corporate entity to sign up as (e.g. an LLC or Corporation), so TestFlight is probably the option you should be looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

TestFlight is by far the easiest option for something like this, but it does come with significant downsides. You need to push out a new version of your app every 60 days, because they expire automatically. Your app also has to pass a "Beta App Review", which it might not actually pass. I'd hope that the Beta App Review process is a bit faster/simpler than review for a generally-available app, but I don't have any experience there.

The other option is the Enterprise Developer program, but for that, you need to send Apple $300 a year, and you have to have a corporate legal entity to sign up.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Mark
I will probably go with the Enterprise since I already have a corp D&B and that is what my current DeveloperId is under.  I will just let the 99.00 id expire and just use the Enterprise for what I need.  Either way the cost is a write-off.  Thanks for your replies...much appreciated.